# How to SELECT data from a table that displays a new column as a percent increase in data from an old column?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am learning SQL and I've been stumped on this question from my book for awhile now.

The questions in this book are asked in a way that I am the DBA for a book store.

So, I have all these tables (Books, Author, Publisher, Customer, Order, etc.) I assume were created by the author of this book (Oracle 11g by Joan Casteel).

This question asks me:

> Management is proposing to increase the price of each book. The amount of the increase will be based on each book’s category, according to the following scale: Computer books, 10%,Fitness books, 15%, Self-Help books, 25%, all other categories, 3%. Create a list that displays each book’s title, category, current retail price, and revised retail price. The prices should be displayed with two decimal places. The column headings for the output should be as follows: Title, Category, Current Price, and Revised Price. Sort the results by category. If there’s more than one book in a category, a secondary sort should be performed on the book’s title.
>
> Create a document to show management the SELECT statement used to generate the results and the results of the statement.

So I know in my SQL statement I need to SELECT the title of these books, category of the books, current retail price of the books, and a revised retail price of the books. For this revised retail price, I need to display a % increase of the old retail price, and do this by category.

This is what I have started doing:

```
SELECT title, category, retail AS "Current Price", retail + (10/100) AS "New Price"
FROM books
WHERE category = 'COMPUTER';
```

When I do this though, I only get results from the COMPUTER category of books and I need results from all categories and display the % increase in price by category.

How do I do it so that I can create that next column as "New Price" and display ALL of the books with their specific % increase in retail price according to the category of book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` statement to do this.

```
SELECT title, category, retail AS "Current Price", retail * CASE category WHEN 'COMPUTER' THEN 1.1 WHEN 'FITNESS' THEN 1.15 ELSE 1.03 END AS "New Price"
FROM books
```

I didn't fill in all the categories and you'll want to check to make sure you know exactly how they are formatted in your field.

Comment: Thank you my friend. Can't believe it is as easy as that!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
SELECT title, category, retail AS "Current Price", retail + (10/100) AS "Revised Price"
FROM books
WHERE category IN ('COMPUTER', 'FITNESS', 'SELF HELP');
```